# Chaining two <animateTransform>s using SMIL

Tags: svg, smil

I'm trying to have two animations in my SVG run one after another.

This is the way they have been written in. They are written into a group with a few primitives inside. I'm trying to make the whole group rotate and then translate.

However when I run this, the transform seems to reset at the end of the first animation

```
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                      id="anim1" 
                      type="rotate"
                      from="0 72 72"
                      to="40 72 72"
                      begin="0s; anim2.end"
                      dur="1s"
                      fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" />
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                      id="anim2"
                      type="translate"
                      from="0 0"
                      to="10 0"
                       begin="anim1.end" dur="0.4s" fill="freeze"/>
```

Comment: Seems is is not quite possible, there is just single transform at any given time: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/post/examples-of-animatetransform ; you could move it along a path instead perhaps, or maybe animate groups(?)

Comment: repeatCount is missing from the second animateTransform so it should do nothing as that attribute is mandatory (unless you specify repeateDur).

Comment: Perhaps you could describe in words what you want this to look like?

Comment: "repeatCount...should do nothing as that attribute is mandatory" - doesn't [that](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/#ComputingActiveDur) say the simple duration (therefore, one repetition) is used if none of repeatCount, repeatDur and end is defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define `additive="sum"` to apply one transformation [on top of the other](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#AdditionAttributes).

So if you want to start the second animation from the end point of the first, add the attribute to the second animation. The way the animations are chained, then the first animation will start again. If you want it to restart from the final position of the second animation, add the attribute also to the first animation.

Comment: Of course the second animation will then run in the rotated coordinate system applied by the first animation. I've no idea if that's what the OP is expecting.

Comment: @RobertLongson. It wasn't what I was expecting but I could easily modify the transform to account for that

Comment: Where in the code do I define additive sum? Which element?

Comment: If you add the attribute to an `<animateTransform>` tag, it applies the animation to every underlying value. If the animated element has a `transform` attribute, it will add to that. If another animation was running earlier, it will add to its final value. If two animations are running in parallel, the resulting value is computed by multiplying both transformation matrices.